# How to generate pdf without any Type3 fonts?

Tags: fonts, pdf, publishing, truetype

For a publisher I have to generate a pdf file which does not contain any Type3 fonts.

Until now I thought that using `pdflatex` on current LaTeX distributions should be enough to get a pdf file without any Type3 fonts, but for the current document this is not true:

```
$ pdffonts paper.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZFUCHW+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi            Type 1            yes yes no      41  0
VNQOQC+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1            yes yes no      42  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no      43  0
NXAFJF+NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal        Type 1            yes yes no      46  0
CBNMRR+NimbusRomNo9L-MediItal        Type 1            yes yes no      48  0
MNSAJN+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu-Slant_167  Type 1            yes yes no      52  0
FJTKHV+CMSY7                         Type 1            yes yes no      53  0
VVITQE+CMMI9                         Type 1            yes yes no      54  0
CHSHRJ+CMR9                          Type 1            yes yes no      56  0
EAPUQB+CMR6                          Type 1            yes yes no      57  0
KBHVYI+CMMI6                         Type 1            yes yes no      58  0
EHULJT+CMTI9                         Type 1            yes yes no      59  0
JLLCEK+CMSY9                         Type 1            yes yes no      61  0
YEIEPQ+CMEX9                         Type 1            yes yes no      64  0
DFKMIY+CMSY8                         Type 1            yes yes no      84  0
NEDAGG+CMSY6                         Type 1            yes yes no      87  0
QDTWCG+MSBM10                        Type 1            yes yes no     127  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     198  0
OKAOPP+CMMI8                         Type 1            yes yes no     199  0
TIGOKK+CMR8                          Type 1            yes yes no     200  0
GWSFMB+CMTI8                         Type 1            yes yes no     201  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     397  0
```

I am surprised that all the Type3 fonts haven't a real name.

The document uses the `sigplanconf` documentclass. For figures only the `tikz` and `listings` packages are used (no graphicx package is used, i.e. no `\includegraphics` is used and no postscript files are embedded).

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with TeX Live:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
```

I have found an [ACM FAQ about Type1 fonts](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq#a14), but it seems to be outdated and the suggested method still yield pdf files with Type3 fonts.

**pk fonts:** Looking for `pk` fonts in the doc.log find I found this ouput:

```
 75i,27n,56p,866b,2711s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 </mnt/max/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ectt0800.600pk> </mnt/max/.texmf-var/fonts
 /pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ectt0900.600pk>{/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc} 
 </mnt/max/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecss0900.600pk>
```

What could be reasons for this? Is some font package missing? Or has it something to do with tikz?

Comment: Installing the cm-super fonts package seems to be the easy answer to me.

Comment: @Ryan, this is already mentioned in an upvoted comment of the accepted answer. Please upvote it as well. You could even post a new short answer to the same effect - which I would upvote.

Comment: In my case, what caused my pdf to have type 3 fonts is that I used the `bbm` package for the mathematical indicator sign.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the end of the log-file of pdflatex. It will tell you which fonts are included and which are bitmap (pk) fonts.

Comment: Thanks, I've found some pk fonts the log file (see the update) - I have no real idea, where they are coming from, though ...

Comment: Install the cm-super fonts.

Comment: thanks a lot,  with the `cm-super` package installed there aren't any Type3 fonts included anymore in the pdf file.

Comment: The `bbm` package, which you might want to use to write blackboard bold numbers, is a source of Type 3 fonts. Try the `dsfont` package instead.

Answer (score 9):

First off, most people use pdflatex nowadays.
Change every image to pdf if possible replacing eps files by pdf using

```
     convert file.eps file.pdf
```

convert is found in the imagemagick package. Remove epsfig and use includegraphics instead.

Next run:

```
     pdffonts final_upload_document.pdf | less
```

to ensure that a type 3 font problem is actually the issue. If it isn't then the problem is most likely related to spaces in file names.

Next run:

```
     pdffonts each_image.pdf
```

to find any type 3 fonts on the individual pdf files to find which image is causing the problem. It could be an xfig or matlab problem, or a problem from another image generator.

If the contained pdfs don't create the issue, then it is most likely an include such as blackboard fonts that is causing the problem inside the source latex file.

Using the above method I found in particular that xfig in addition to matlab can cause the same artefacts if you are using export to latex+pdf part.

When you find the pdf + latex file you can run:

```
  xfig -specialtext -latexfonts -startlatexFont default
```

to start up xfig with the right settings. You also might find as in my case that the xfig image was generated some years ago that was to go into the paper, and that it now doesn't even open in newer versions of xfig giving a sigsegv fault. In this case your only option is to regenerate the image using the above xfig call.

Comment: Very interesting, I found the exact source of the xfig Type 3 font problem. It occurs not in the text fonts, but in the patterned polylines. If you use filled instead of patterned polylines and export to pdf/latex, you will then find that pdffonts will not return a type 3 font on your pdf.

Answer (score 8):

A Type 3 font is *not* by default a bitmap font. It means only *not a Type 1 one*. This is the reason why a Type 3 font can also be a vector font. If there is no listed pk font in the log file, then you have such a type 3 font included. It may also be loaded by an image with `\includegraphics`

Comment: Ok, I've found some pk fonts and I am not using `includegraphics` (updated the question).

Comment: then show exactly your font setting in the preamble. However, it looks like that you are using the package times instead of mathptmx. Right?

Comment: no, I am not using the `times` package - the system was missing the `cm-super` package - see my comment to Ulrike Fischer's answer.

Answer (score 7):

When including graphics coming from matplotlib, they may contain a Type3 font. However, matplotlib [can be instructed](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) to use tex rendering and the correct font family:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and in my case figures generated by matplotlib were the ultimate culprit. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: I tried this and ran `pdffonts fig.pdf` on the output figure from matplotlib and it was still chock full of the type 3 fonts

Comment: This did not work for me, but i agree matplotlib figures were the culprit. This other solution worked for me: http://phyletica.org/matplotlib-fonts/

Answer (score 7):

I also had an issue with an image generated by matplotlib, and tried other suggestions proposed here but none of them really helped. What finally worked was an advice I found here (http://phyletica.org/matplotlib-fonts/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
```

After I regenerated images my PDF was finally free of Type3 fonts.

Comment: This is the best solution for matplotlib, IMO, as it doesn't seem to otherwise change the appearance.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by adding the following command to the head of my latex file:

```
\pdfminorversion=4              % tell pdflatex to generate PDF in version 1.4
```

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit in what *this* is ... answers get reordered by votes and the antecedent is no longer clear. Maybe this answer should be a comment to another answer (than it it not moved away from it)?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to say why this worked for me. In case somebody else has insight, he is free to edit my answer and extend it.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to the answer by Eamonn Kenny: once you have identified the offending figure containing the problematic font, opening it in Inkscape and exporting it to PDF with the export option "convert text to paths" gets rid of all fonts.

In my case, the publisher website still gave a vague error message, and the solution by Peter Pablo solved it finally: forcing PDF v1.4 ensured compatibility

N.B. I have too low a reputation to comment or upvote, hence this post.

Answer (score 1):

cm-super did not work for me, as it turns out that the Type-3 fonts were loaded from the pictures. The easiest fix: just save your pdf file with Apple Preview or Adobe Reader and it will do the trick!

Comment: Welcome! This does not answer this question because you, unlike the OP, were including external images which used type3 fonts. On the other hand, the OP, unlike you, had type3 fonts solely as a result of not having type1 versions of the T1-encoded CM fonts available. Obviously, `cm-super` won't help in your case, but neither will your suggestion help in the OP's. That is, you have a quite distinct problem which is unrelated to this one. Have I missed something?

Comment: @cfr it might be a different issue, but googling brought me here, and my problem is more similar to Mauro's problem so it is helpful to me to know of this approach.

Comment: @FionaSmith To say that it does not answer the question is not to say that it may not be a useful answer to a different question. So it may be useful to you, but it still doesn't answer this question. For one thing, the OP clearly can't use Apple Preview and almost certainly can't use Adobe Reader either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using figures generated by matplotlib and these figures are the source of font type, there are two key settings: `pdf.fonttype` and `ps.fonttype`. You have to change these settings from the default of 3 to the alternative 42. You can do this in your `matplotlibrc` file with:

```
pdf.fonttype : 42
ps.fonttype : 42
```

Or, you can change these settings in your code using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
```

Comment: Since the OP explicitly does not use external graphics or references matplotlib in any way, this doesn't really answer the question. It might still be useful for matplotlib users, but I think that it should at least mention that the settings are related to matplotlib and that this solution only applies if the issue is caused by using that library.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I edited the answer.  In my case, these settings to matplotlib solved the Type3 font issue.

Comment: RT. This did the trick for me too, matplotlib version 3.6.2. (I agree with Marcel Kruger that the OP didn't ask about matplotlib, so it might be useful to post this somewhere else too)