# NSF fastlane removes hyperref links from PDFs when fontspec is used

Tags: hyperref, luatex, pdf, fontspec

I'm trying to submit proposal documents to NSF Fastlane.  I'm generating PDF documents using `lualatex`.  My file contains `hyperref` links internally and externally, but they are removed by Fastlane's upload PDF redistillation.  The text remains and is visible, but there is no link to click on.

Here is my minimal non-working example.  I compile it using `lualatex` from the TeXLive 2016 distribution on Windows.  The culprit seems to be `fontspec`.  If I remove that line, the links work, but I'd like to use `fontspec` so I can choose fonts.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,twoside=false,onecolumn]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{fontspec} % This seems to be the problem.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{sec}
This is an explicit external url: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}.

This is an external link: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{Link}.

This is an internal link to Sec.~\ref{sec}.
\end{document}
```

My questions are:

- What about `fontspec` makes my links get eaten by Fastlane?
- Is there a workaround?

**Edit:**
The issue is something with how Fastlane handles fonts when it re-distills PDFs.
For example, in the example give, if I run `pdffonts` on file generated by `lualatex` I get the following output:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
TYJNNQ+PalatinoLinotype-Roman        CID TrueType      yes yes yes     19  0
```

but after uploading the file to Fastlane and re-downloading, the output of `pdffonts` gives

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
EKFDNL+PalatinoLinotype-Roman        CID TrueType      yes yes no      31  0
EKFFKE+PalatinoLinotype-Roman        TrueType          yes yes no      36  0
EKFFNF+PalatinoLinotype-Roman        TrueType          yes yes no       2  0
```

Somehow the font is being broken up and re-encoded, breaking hyperlinks in the process.

**Edit 2:** I'm uncertain that the fonts are really the issue.  After changing the fonts, `\url{}` links work, but `\href{}{}` links still do not.

Comment: You are not using hyperref in your example, so whatever links you are getting are a result of the pdfviewer heuristic.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Sorry, that was a pasting error.  The actual example does have hyperref.  Now edited to fix.

Comment: Don't load `fontenc` when using `lualatex`.  Does that change anything?  I don't recall having this problem, and use `fontspec` and `lualatex` also.

Comment: @AlanMunn - If I remove fontspec then there is no problem.

Comment: But you shouldn't be loading `fontenc`.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Sorry, I misread your comment.  `fontspec` vs. `fontenc`.  However, removing `fontenc` does not solve the problem.  I will edit the example to remove it.

Comment: You are using different fonts with and without fontspec and it is possible that this changes the distillation process, but imho you can't do much about it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Do the fonts change if I load `fontspec` but do not explicitly declare a font?

Comment: Sure, look at the end of the log-file. It will show you the fonts you include.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - you were right.  The fine print on Fastlane says that Type 3 fonts will not work.  If I explicitly declare some ttf fonts (e.g. Times New Roman and Courier New), then the distillation preserves the links.

Comment: This link helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18687/how-to-generate-pdf-without-any-type3-fonts

Comment: That would explain why I had no problems since I declared fonts explicitly.

Comment: @AlanMunn But it shouldn't be using type3 fonts if `fontspec` is loaded as `fontspec` declares fonts itself.

Comment: @cfr The problem wasn't specifically Type 3 fonts, but any type other than Type 1 or TTF.  I tried to clarify below.

Comment: @TedCorcovilos Ah. OK. Yes. It will use opentype by default. (And Latin Modern rather than Computer Modern.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Well, if it won't accept opentype fonts, it makes sense. This seems extremely odd, even by the standards of submissions generally, which certainly set high oddity standards.

Comment: Also, the PDF versions need to be <=1.4.  I don't understand the various PDF versions, but the fonts are stored differently in 1.5 and up.  I'll amend my answer below.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I would be surprised if that were the case. But Fastlane is an old system, so one never knows.  But in the last grant that I worked on we used `fontspec` and the Mac Times font, so I don't  know for sure.

Comment: Disregard my last comment.  See new edit to OP.

Comment: The font issue may be unrelated to the hyperlink issue.  After fixing the fonts, explicit URLs (those displaying http) work, but as @UlrikeFischer mentions above, that could be the PDF reader inferring a link from the text.  Doing something like `\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{Link}` still doesn't work.  I'm editing the example to test that case also.

Comment: You are asking us about some online service that does stuff to PDFs. Ask the purveyors of that service, not us.

Comment: I didn't mean that the fonts in themselves are the problem. But they probably influence the way the pdf are handled: Fastlane probably checks the pdf at upload. If it is as they want it they leave it alone (and the links intact), if not they correct it and in this process destroy the links/annotations like e.g. using `\includepdf` would destroy them.

Comment: If it redistills the PDF regardless, I don't think there is much you can do: it will destroy the links. Did links work for you, @AlanMunn?

Comment: @cfr I checked back and we didn't include any links it turns out.

Comment: BTW, PDFs generated from MS-Word, for example, do not have their links broken when re-distilled.  There is some bad interaction between LaTeX and the distiller.

Comment: @TedCorcovilos It isn't re-distilling them, though. The equivalent would be to export the Word document as PDF and then upload it and see if the links survived. I'm assuming you're talking about uploading the original Word document, so it is being turned into PDF for the first time.

Comment: @cfr Yes, if I convert a Word document to PDF (using built-in Print to PDF) then upload, the links are preserved.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Fastlane's PDF distiller can't process all fonts.  See page 1346 of the Fastlane docs: https://www.research.gov/common/attachment/Desktop/FastLane_Help.pdf (Warning: the file is 30MB large.)

The instructions explicitly say to use **only Type 1 or TrueType fonts**.  In particular, `hyperref` uses the mono font family for typesetting URLs, so this must be explicitly set.

That is the technical issue.  But also, per the most recent NSF guidelines (https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappg17_1/pappg_2.jsp#IIB2), the only allowed fonts are

> Arial, Courier New, or Palatino Linotype at a font size of 10 points or larger;
>
> Times New Roman at a font size of 11 points or larger; or
>
> Computer Modern family of fonts at a font size of 11 points or larger.

Of these choices, I believe the only monospaced fonts are `Courier New` or `Computer Modern Typewriter` (if you have the .ttf version), so it is necessary to use something like

```
\setmonofont{Courier New}
```

to override the default (e.g. `lm-mono`) or otherwise disable all monospaced fonts in the document.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53962/why-are-urls-typeset-with-monospace-fonts-by-default